# exclude only js files from gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm now working on a project and I am going to change the `.js` files of this project. I want to track my changes on this project and I want to have a git repository which have only the `.js` files.

this `.js` files can be in any folder in this project with any depth.

I try this in my `.gitignore` file but have no luck:

```
/*
!/*.js
```

can you put me in a right direction?
thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these two lines to your **.gitignore** inside root directory of your repository. It should then probably track only **.js** files.

```
*.*
!*.js
```